# Need to Click on Span

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I need to click Purchase

HTML is as follows:

```
<li class="treeview"> <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span>Purchase</span> <span class="pull-right-container"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i> </span> </a> <ul class="treeview-menu" style="display: none;"> <li class="treeview "><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Purchase Request</a></li>
```

I tried this:

```
WebElement purchase = driver.findElement(By.tagName("span"));
purchase.click()
```

But not working: Please help me, Am a beginner in selenium

Comment: Please add relvant HTML and read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please share the HTML source?

Comment: <span>Purchase</span>

Comment: <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span>Purchase</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li class="treeview "><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Purchase Request</a></li>

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Rather than adding relevant info in the comments, please edit the question and add it there. You can add a comment or respond to someone in comments notifying them of the updated question. This makes it easier for later readers to find all the info needed to answer the question. Don't forget to add a tag for the language you are using... Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **HTML** you have shared, you can try this **xpath** :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Purchase']/parent::a"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the link with text as **Purchase** you can use the following solution:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='treeview']/a//span[contains(.,'Purchase')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css selector :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".treeview a")).click();
```